# Cokernels in Co-Cartesian Diagram are isomorphic.

Tags: homological-algebra

We assume the category is abelian. Let the below be a co-cartesian diagram. A co-cartesian diagram is just the dual of a cartesian diagram. 
\begin{array}{ccc}
      A& \xrightarrow{f} & B \\[3pt]
      \downarrow {a} & & \downarrow{b} \\
      C& \xrightarrow{g} & D
\end{array}

I want to prove that $cok(a) \simeq cok(b)$. This is a part of a proposition from the book cohomology of sheaves by Birger Iversen. I could prove it for the case of abelian groups but somehow i couldn't transform the procedure into language of arrows. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: this proof is wrong, $d$ cannot be defined as written.

We prove the statement for $f$ and $g$, being analogous in the other one.
Let us name $p:B\to coker (f)$ and $q:D \to coker (g)$.

First of all, notice that we can complete our diagram with a new map $\varphi:coker (f) \to coker (g)$.
Indeed, since $qbf=qga=(qg)a=0$, $qb:B \to coker(g)$ can be factorized via $coker(f)$. We then consider $d:D\to B$ determined by $1:B\to B$ and $0:C\to B$. $pdg=0$ since $dg=0$ by requirement, and so $pd$ factorizes through $q$: there exists $\psi: coker (g) \to coker (f)$ making
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
      D& \xrightarrow{f} & coker(g) \\[3pt]
      \downarrow {d} & & \downarrow{\psi} \\
      B& \xrightarrow{g} & coker(f)
\end{array}$$
commutative.

Next, it suffices to show that they are one the inverse of the other. Since $db=1$, we easily obtain $\psi\varphi p = p$ and because $p$ is an epimorphism $\psi\varphi=1$. In particular, notice that $\ker (\varphi) = 0 = coker( \psi)$. The other part is done by checking that $coker (\varphi)=0$. Let $h: coker (g) \to X$ be such that $h\varphi=0$. We consider the map from $D\to X$ given by $0=h\varphi p =hqb : B \to X$ and $0:C\to X$. The obtained map is trivially the zero one. On the other side, also $hq$ satisfies the required properties: $hqg=0:C \to X$ and $hqb=0:B\to X$. Therefore $hq=0$ because the morphism $D\to X$ is unique by definition. Since $q$ is an epimorphism, $h=0$ and so we have obtained that $h\varphi=0$ implies $h=0$. So, $coker(\varphi)=0$ and $\varphi$ is an epimorphism. Finally, $\varphi =\varphi 1 = \varphi \psi \varphi$ and by epimorphism property $\varphi\psi=1$.

In fact, the last part is too formal: in an abelian category every monomorphism is a kernel and every epimorphism is a cokernel, therefore it is easy to see that monomorphism and epimorphism implies isomorphism.

Sorry for being 2 years late.

Comment: How do you get your map $d$? Why is $1_B f = 0\cdot a =0$, which you use for the existence of $d$?

Comment: You don't have any map $d$ in that way, you're right.

Comment: Anyway, the map $D \to \mathrm{coker} f$ (which exists) suffices for your argument. Btw., do you know if the converse statement is true (i.e., if both maps on cokernels are iso, then the square is cocartesian)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use Mitchell's theorem: an Abelian category is equivalent to a full subcategory of a category of R-modules, where R is a ring.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell's_embedding_theorem

Comment: Thanks. I will look it up. But are there ways in which you donot have to use this theorem?  Since the book doesnot talks about this theorem.