# Are commutative squares that induce iso on cokernels cocartesian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Does the converse of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1539921/cokernels-in-co-cartesian-diagram-are-isomorphic/2757673?noredirect=1#comment8222854_2757673) hold true? Explicitly, is a commutative square
$$\begin{matrix}
A & \stackrel a \to & X\\\llap{\scriptstyle a'}\downarrow&&\downarrow\rlap{\scriptstyle b'}\\Y & \stackrel b \to &  B
\end{matrix}$$
cocartesian if the induced maps $\operatorname{coker}a \to \operatorname{coker}b$ and $\operatorname{coker}a' \to\operatorname{coker}b'$ are isomorphisms?

Actually, I see no reason why this should be true, but maybe someone has a nice counter example and/or can elaborate on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: in the diagram below, the top and left arrows send $1 \mapsto 1$; then all cokernels are $0$, but the pushout $\mathbb{Z}/2 \sqcup_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}/2$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2$.
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb{Z} @>>> \mathbb{Z}/2 \\
@VVV @VVV\\
\mathbb{Z}/2 @>>> 0
\end{CD}